# Check if String token contains string char and String number value

Tags: java, string, numbers, compare, character

1)I need to check if String contains a String characters what will be the corect way how to do it ?

2) Are some ways how to corectly transform String to number and then compare theese two number s? Like String = "House":1234 is equal to "House":1234 but no to "house":123 
Priview:

```
String token ="123"; False
String token = "ā123"; or other characters True utc.

if(isChars(token)){
   Long value = toLong(token);
}
```

THANKS!

//EDIT
 public BigDecimal eval() {

```
    Stack<BigDecimal> stack = new Stack<BigDecimal>();

    for (String token : getRPN()) {
        if (operators.containsKey(token)) {
            BigDecimal v1 = stack.pop();
            BigDecimal v2 = stack.pop();
            stack.push(operators.get(token).eval(v2, v1));
        } else if (variables.containsKey(token)) {
            stack.push(variables.get(token).round(mc));
        } else if (functions.containsKey(token.toUpperCase())) {
            Function f = functions.get(token.toUpperCase());
            ArrayList<BigDecimal> p = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>(f.getNumParams());
            for (int i = 0; i < f.numParams; i++) {
                p.add(0, stack.pop());
            }
            BigDecimal fResult = f.eval(p);
            stack.push(fResult);
        } else if (isDate(token)) {
            Long date = null;
            try {
                date = SU.sdf.parse(token).getTime();
            } catch (ParseException e) {/* IGNORE! */
            }
            // mylog.pl("LONG DATE : "+new BigDecimal(date, mc));
            stack.push(new BigDecimal(date, mc));
        }//TODO HERE 
        else if (isChar(token)){
            Long cha = toLong(token);
            stack.push(new BigDecimal(cha, mc));
            //TODO ENDS HERE
        }
        else {
            // mylog.pl("Token : "+ token);
            stack.push(new BigDecimal(token, mc));
        }
    }
    return stack.pop().stripTrailingZeros();
}
```

Comment: Any problem with the `equals()` method?. BTW I didn't get your question at all.

Comment: Hi! I need to check if token contains alphabet characters , then this token transform to Long or BigDecimal and compare. Of course i know abouet equals() but this transform need for Custom function expresion execution

Comment: Like dates got method: Long date = sdf.parse(token).getTime(); Are something similar with Strings ?

Comment: Could you give some example data? Your question is unclear - often example input and output are the best and simplest way to communicate an idea.

Comment: I am reciving String token it can be only numbers,date or varchar. I need to catch this varchar and tranform it to Long. Edited 1st post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way for determing whether string contains any chars is nice class `StringUtils` from [apache-commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) library.

It contains several methods for analyzing string's contents. It seems that in your case you can use `StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(CharSequence cs)` or negation of `StringUtils.isNumeric(CharSequence cs)`'s result.

What about second part of your question, so I do not see here necessety of extracting numbers from string. You can compare strings `"House":1234` and `"house":123` using standard `String.equals()` method.

Comment: Your idea is right, but i cant compare two string, i need to transform String to number and then compare number because Custom utility can contains user definied function calls and values from many entity's The only one value who i can compare is BigDecimal

Answer (score 1):

```
Long l;
try{
    l = Long.parseLong(token);
} catch(NumberFormatException e){
    //contains non-numeric character(s)
}
```

As for "transforming varchar into Long" - that sounds rather impossible, we do not have universally accepted way of doing that, and you did not provide one. However if I guess correctly that what you want is the number within the string disregarding the characters - you want regular expressions. The code you want could look like:

```
if (!StringUtils.isNumeric(token)){
   String stripped = token.replaceAll("\\D","");
   Long l = Long.parseLong(stripped);
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String) It will throw an error if token can't be interpreted as a Long.

Comment: Then this way does not fit

Comment: Umm... Ok, so it appears I did not understand the question. What do you want to happen in "a123" case? You want to strip the string of non numeric characters and get the number that is inside?